# Logistic regression on 2 concentric circles

Tags: regression, machine-learning

If we have 2 concentric circles of different radius and points on the same circle corresponds to the same data class then can model this problem to be solved by logistic regression. I don't think we can since the data points are not linearly separable.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, yes, it can.

Let's say the circles are of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, just to make things easier to follow (*).

Then the following functional form works when thresholded to classify the points:

$$ P(y | x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1)} $$

On the circle of radius one half:

$$ P(y | x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1)} = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(-0.5)} > 0.5$$

On the circle of radius three halves

$$ P(y | x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1)} = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(0.5)} < 0.5$$

So if you threshold the probabilistic predictions at $0.5$, you'll classify correctly.

Note that you *do* need to add some derived features, in this case the squares of the coordinates.   This is very common in practice to deal with these kinds of situations.

(*) Note that this isn't really a restriction, you can always scale your coordinates in a way to map any two concentric circles to this specific situation.

Comment: I think the underlying question is *how would you discover* such a functional form when presented with noisy data generated from the given model?